# Let $E \subset R$ and let $f$ be a real-valued function on $E$ that is continuous at $p \in E$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $E \subset R$ and let $f$ be a real-valued function on $E$ that is continuous at $p$ in $E$. If $f(p) > 0$, prove that there exists an $\alpha > 0$ and a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) \ge \alpha$ for all $x \in N_\delta(p) \cap E$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A:=f(p)>0$. $f$ is continuous at $p$ so for all $\epsilon>0,$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(p)|<\epsilon$ whenever $x\in N_{\delta}(p)\cap E$. In particular, pick $\epsilon=f(p)-\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is any number that satisfies $0<\alpha<f(p)$ (such a number exists by the Archimedean property of the real numbers). For example, let $\alpha=f(p)/2$. Then there exists a $\delta$ as before such that

$|f(x)-f(p)|<f(p)-\alpha$, whenever $x\in N_{\delta}(p)\cap E$.

The inequality resolves to $\alpha-f(p)<f(x)-f(p)<f(p)-\alpha$. In particular, the first inequality gives you $\alpha<f(x)$.

Comment: thanks a lot! that really helped me understand it